# Replace all "\n" with ","

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a textarea and I want to replace "\n" with "," in it's value.

```
var valuetxtarr = $("#txtarr").val();
var valuetxtarrs = valuetxtarr.replace("/\n/g",",");
alert(valuetxtarrs);
```

But it don't work?Why?Where I have mistake?

Comment: Remember that jQuery is not a synonym for JavaScript. I've added the tag for you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to remove the quotes (otherwise it's looking for that string), like this:

```
var valuetxtarr = $("#txtarr").val();
var valuetxtarrs = valuetxtarr.replace(/\n/g,",");
alert(valuetxtarrs);​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/VwwC4/)

Comment: @lam3r4370 you should accept an answer when it is resolving your problems.

Comment: @Jens - He can't for about 15 minutes after asking...it was a throttle set to encourage more answers a while back :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var valuetxtarr = $("#txtarr").val(); 
var valuetxtarrs = valuetxtarr.replace(/\n/g,","); 
alert(valuetxtarrs);
```