# How to replace a newline with a single space in a javascript (Google App Script) value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The line I use to collect the texts is as follows:

```
array_Text.push([obj_data.data[int_i].text]);
```

Values are received this way:

```
Test 1!
Test 2.
Test 3
```

The values I would like to be adjusted and remove the new lines, putting in place a single space like this:

```
Test! Test 2. Test 3
```

In the spreadsheet I use the function:

```
=SUBSTITUTE("value","
"," ")
```

But I would like the values to come prepared straight from the script, without having to use formulas in the spreadsheet. How could I proceed?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: I think that this thread might be the answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3148618 It's like `console.log("Test 1!\nTest 2.\nTest 3".replace(/\n/g," "))`.